# Повторная дедуплекация

Tags: windows-server, hdd

Есть сервер на Win 2012 R2 основная роль которого "файловое хранилище" и предоставление доступа к этим папкам пользователям домена. Так же, поскольку файлов много (больше одного ТБ), была включена дедуплекация.

Но так получилось, что Win server пришлось переустановить. Теперь я имею следующую проблему:

большая часть файлов стала недоступна. То есть, если открывается, например, презентация, то PP не может её открыть, тоже самое может быть и в ворде и в других приложениях. Когда пытаешся копировать файл по сети, получаешь ошибку: error 0x80070780.

Собственно вопрос:

Повторное включение дедуплекации решит проблему? Или же нужно делать так, как пишут некоторые столкнувшейся с этим, извлечение диска из одного ПК и подключение к другому? Вытащить диск из сервера мне будет проблематично.

Comment: А после переустановки повторно включить дедуплекацию пробовали? Видела сообщения в сети, что помогает. Почему бы не попробовать?

Comment: Да, я сделал это :) Именно, просто включил и всё заработало. Страшноватенько было :) Я боялся, что если включу эту фичу, то сервер может и не подумать, что раздел уже подвергся дедуплекации и он снова решит сделать тоже самое, в итоге файлы придут в негодность.

Comment: Тогда, ответьте на свой же вопрос, укажите как делали и отметьте его "как ответ", чтобы Ваш вопрос не висел без ответа )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решён. Я на свой страх и риск включил роль дедуплекации снова. После перезагрузки в Диспетчере сервера сразу появилась информация о том, на сколько процентов было сохранено место на диске. Доступ к файлам так-же появился сразу после перезагрузки.

Comment: Если вопрос решен, то отметьте ответ галкой )